# MASM code for finding prime numbers not working

Tags: assembly, masm

I have the following code for finding prime numbers:

```
   isPrime PROC; checks if a number is prime by dividing out values less than it until it finds one that has a remainder of 0
         ;or the test value reaches the number

retest:
inc testNum
mov eax, testPrime
cmp eax, testNum
je  prime
mov edx, 0
mov eax, testPrime
mov ebx, testNum
div ebx
cmp edx, ZERO
jg retest
mov eax, 1
mov testNum, eax
inc testPrime
prime:
ret
isPrime ENDP
```

The way it should be working is that testPrime is the number being tested.  It then checks testNum, which starts at 2 (1 at the beginning but is immediately incremented) and divides testPrime by testNum.  If the remainder is zero, it divides out, and testPrime is not a prime number.  testPrime is incremented, testNum is reset and the whole thing starts again.  If testPrime and testNum are equal, then it is a prime, and the procedure exits (which causes another part of the program to print it, and call the procedure again after incrememnting testPrime).

What is happening is that it is printing every single integer from 2 to however many primes are requested.  I've done some debugging, and it seems that edx is getting a weirdly large number somehow, but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it.  Because of my poor placement of debug breakpoints I didn't realize that the edx register is being used properly.  However, two other problems were present in my code.

Working code is below.  Notice the new jmp command right before the prime: tag, and the new reset of testNum before the return.

```
isPrime PROC; checks if a number is prime by dividing out values less than it until it finds one that has a remainder of 0
         ;or the test value reaches the number
 retest:
inc testNum
mov eax, testPrime
cmp eax, testNum
je  prime
mov edx, 0
mov eax, testPrime
mov ebx, testNum
div ebx
mov eax, edx
cmp eax, ZERO
jg retest
mov eax, 1
mov testNum, eax
inc testPrime
jmp retest
 prime:
mov eax, 1
mov testNum, eax
ret
isPrime ENDP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data segment

 ddd db 00h,00h,00h

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment

proc zzz
push ax
push dx 
push bx    
lea di,ddd
mov bx,10  
div bl
mov ds:[di+2],ah
add ds:[di+2],48
mov ah,0
div bl
mov ds:[di+1],ah
add ds:[di+1],48
mov ah,0
div bl
mov ds:[di],ah
add ds:[di],48 
mov ah, 2
mov dx,ds:[di]
int 21h
mov dx,ds:[di+1]
int 21h
mov dx,ds:[di+2]
int 21h 
pop bx
pop dx
pop ax
ret
endp
start:

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

mov si,03d
mov di,50d 
wwww:mov ax,si
mov bp,si
sub bp,2       
mov bx,01h
mov cx,2     
fff:mov dx,00h
push ax
div cx 
pop ax
cmp dx,00 
je sss
jmp con1
sss:mov bx,00h 
con1:inc cx
dec bp
jnz fff    
cmp bx,01h
je xxxx
jne mmmm
xxxx:call zzz
mmmm:inc si
cmp si,50d
je bbb
jmp wwww
bbb:ends 

ends

end start
```